# substitution of someaddress.com on local desktop computer

Tags: linux, webserver, hosts

Here is VDS server with ip(for example 105.123.123.123) with working apache service. 
And there is a desktop computer with linux on board(but really I presume there is no difference). I need to type on web browser address like someaddress.com and to see website situated at my server.
My /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
105.123.123.123  someaddress.com
105.123.123.123 www.someaddress.com
```

But it doesn't work. I see real someaddress.com website. What can be wrong. It will be great if you help me with that.

P.S. Why I need this. There is one project with fixed links(like someaddress.com/inf). And I need to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your distribution is preferring DNS over values in */etc/hosts*.
Check */etc/nsswitch.conf*. It should have a hosts line something like:

```
hosts: files dns
```

Just make sure *files* comes before *dns*.

Comment: unfortunately nsswitch.conf contain correct information.

My nsswitch.conf:

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis

Comment: I don't know then. It works for me. Maybe your browser is caching someaddress.com with out doing a lookup. Trying dropping the browser cache before hitting someaddress.com.